# SQLite fmdb: If I can't delete a column, would deleting the column data be okay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I currently have an SQLite table that contains the user's information (first name, last name, age, IP address).

However, I don't want the App to store the IP address anymore. The only solutions that I seem to have are to create another table and transfer all the data to it or just delete the address data (set it to NULL). I choose setting it to NULL because it seems easier and the App works very well when I do this with no repercussions. Also, I made it where if the user logs in, the IP address column isn't even going to exist.

My concern is if there is any reason why I shouldn't do this at all? I haven't run into any issues yet, but just in case I thought I'll ask.

Edit: Forgot to mention this, but there is only 1 row of data for the user.

Comment: So, it appears that SQLite doesn't support "drop column" :/, but, [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/) explains at least way you "might" be able to do it.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like quite a bit of task to complete just to make sure one piece of data isn't showing. That's why I set the column data to null. Not sure if this is okay to do. Everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **you don’t need to drop the column**. It’s too much unnecessary work for 1 row of data.

> You won’t have any issues because of that spare column

**You can “drop” it** pretty easily if you like, by just creating a new table with a single row, it sounds scary, but you’ll be surprised with the short time it takes you to do it.